# dynamically adding item to listview with the result given by the child activity

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-intent

i am stuck while developing my program.
i am not able to find the solution

what i am doing is, from one activity (A) i am calling other activity (B) for result.

now in activity A i have a list view.
for that listview i have an ArrayAdapter
the code for that purpose is :

```
String []name_list = myarraylist.toArray(new String[myarraylist.size()]);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.textview,name_list);

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Activity A is ListActivity.

now , i have a menu option, clicking on which takes me to another activity, an returns with a result string.
up till this point , everything works fine. the string is also returned by the activity B.
now i want to add the string (the returned one) to the listview.....
how should i do that? 
i tried doing it in onActivityResult() itself  and also in onResume() 
but i couldnt make it working.

help!

EDIT:
   code for onActivityResult is :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bundle mybundle = data.getExtras();

    String pro_name= mybundle.getString("profile_name");

    myarraylist.add(pro_name);

getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: you should receive the value from activity B in `onActivityResult()`. post the code of that method.

Comment: can i see your onActivityResult() and setResult() in activity (B) code ?

Comment: i have added my code in the EDITed question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Arrayadapter add method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add(T) in onactivityResult and call notifyDatasetchanged http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()